# Help to resolve this optimization problem with lagrangians? Cheeers!

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

So I have this problem, and what I do is to set up the max problem.( for Lambda Ill use the letter "L" and for what it looks like gamma Ill use letter "g" )

Objective function is B*ln(x-t) and the constraint is P*x=y

I set up the Lagrangian as follows  B*ln(x-g)+L(y-P*x).

I then write the FOC , so derivatives of the Langrangian in respect to x , y and L.

(1)      respect to x   =>  ((b)/(x-g))-L*P = 0

(2)      respect to y   =>   L =0

(3)      respect to L   =>   y-P*x = 0

So I made it up to here, I thinkI have made some mistakes as equation number 2 doesnt really make sense, I had never done an optimization problem with paramters. Any help please?

Comment: As $y$ is fixed, differentiating wrt it doesn't make sense, so eqn (2) is not valid.  Your other equations also need to be written in terms of $x_i$ as there are $n$ of those variables, not just one $x$.

Comment: ok, the way I have set up the LAgrangian is correct? then why I have to write the first equation in terms of xi? there must be only one x that optimize the objective function, it is true that this x is dependent on B and G though , thats why I write X, because thats the endogenous variable, B and G are exogenous..what would be the FOC then? in terms of x and in terms of L only? cheers

Comment: What is $x$? It is not defined in the problem. It is the quantity of what consumed out of the n goods?

Comment: yes , X is the amount of good you consume. I understand that there is only one good , defined as X

Comment: The problem (in the picture you posted) however states there are $n$ goods being consumed, and $x_i$ denotes the amount of each.  At the optimal state, you will have some value for each $x_i$ to consume.  So if thats correct, you cannot replace all of that with one $x$.

Comment: Mmm, I think that what it says is that he consumes n goods, of a one same good, like he consumes n potatoes(x)...not that he consumes n quantity of any good.

Comment: Ok, last hint. If there is only one good, there is no optimisation problem, just substitute from the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Objective function is B*ln(x-t) and the constraint is P*x=y

Either you are ignoring the presence of multiple goods, or are using some vectorized notation. I won't do either, so for me the objective is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \ln(x_i-\gamma_i)$$
and the constraint is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i = y$$
The Lagrangian is
$$L=\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \ln(x_i-\gamma_i) + \lambda \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i - y \right)$$
By the way, what are we optimizing over? Over amounts $x_i$, I think. The quantity $y$ is not consumer's to choose: of course, if s/he could choose the income to have, the optimization problem becomes pointless: just have yourself a lot of money and buy all you want. This is why taking the derivative with respect to $y$ leads to an absurd equation.

The relevant partial derivatives are those with respect to variables: $x_i$ and the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$. 
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\beta_i}{x_i-\gamma_i} + \lambda p_i$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i x_i - y$$ 
These should be equated to $0$, etc.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much ;)

Comment: also...if you have some time, could you have a look at this post of mine ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536707/why-this-optimization-problem-is-solved-like-that-any-explanations-help-thank . Cheers!